# Finding bad links to use for the Google disavow links tool

Tags: seo, google-search-console, disavow-links

So, I have found domains that link to my site, and they seem to be banned as searching for `site:domain.com` on them doesn't produce any results at all.

I now need to use the Google disavow links tool to remove the bad links, but it asks to import a `.txt` file with links only and I don't have the links.

Is there any automated way to find bad link URLs without buying expensive memberships to premium SEO sites/tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best idea is to login to your Google Webmaster Tools, where you will see all the sites that are linking to your domain.

You'll have to check them one by one and try to remove the links from the bad ones. If you cannot (for whatever reason) remove the backlink to your domain, then you can add those sites or the whole domains to the disavow tool.

For example to add 1 domain you may upload to the disavow tool a .txt file with this content:

```
domain:a-bad-link-domain.com
```

Comment: is it a good practice to disawow whole domains as you explained? Also, are these domains "marked bad" forever? Is there a way to make them "good" or "unban" or "un disawow" in the future?

Comment: in internet there is a plenty of bad sites. They just put backlinks. If the site is bad or your are almost sure it's not a good site (for example a robot made site, that content is generated or copied automatically), then it's better to add to the disavow tool the whole domain. Often happens that you have visibility of only 1 page that is linking to you, but it may happen that there are a plenty of other pages in that domain that link to you.
Yes, you can always edit the disavow list in future. You'll just have to download the old uploaded list, edit it, and upload it back again.

Comment: @CamSpy Please don't follow up with new questions via comments.  Use the "Ask Question" tab to ask new questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get good free data by searching through a month or more of your website's log files.  Anytime somebody clicks to your site from another site their browser sends the other site as a "referrer".  Web servers typically include referrer information in the log files.

As long as the site that is linking to you sent even a single click your way during the time period in which you are searching the logs, then you will find the links and be able to disavow them.